# Validating 'unique per user' rows in database in Laravel 4

Tags: php, sql, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have a db table that looks like this:

```
Schema::create('types', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('label', 128);
    $table->boolean('unique_items');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My validation currently looks like this:

```
// Validate input for new Type
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
    array(
        'label' => 'required|min:3|max:128|unique:types',
    )
);
```

What I would like to achieve is a user being able to create a `Type` where the `label` is unique to their `user_id`. So if user `1` makes a `Type` labeled `books` he could not create another one, however user `2` could create a `books` type as well.

As far as I can tell from the Laravel docs it is only possible to exclude a user from the unique search but not compare based on their `id`. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add additional where clause to make a composite unique item, for example:

```
"label" => "required|min:3|max:128|unique:types,label,null,id,user_id,{$user_id}"
```

All you need to pass the `$user_id` here so this will make sure a type is unique to this user only. You may declare a method inside your `model/Type` like this:

```
public function setUniqueValidationRuleForType($user_id)
{
    static::$rules["label"] = "required|min:3|max:128|unique:types,label,null,id,user_id,{$user_id}";
    return $this; // This is optional
}
```

Now, before you create a new entry, just call this method to allow another entry for the user with the `ID` you passed in to the method. You may also check the [documentation here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique).

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what the `null,id,user_id` represent? The docs seem a bit vague and I'm still not really understanding why this works/how the query is constructed.

Comment: This will generate a query like: `select count(*) as aggregate from `types` where `label` = 'some_value' and `user_id` = $user_id`. The `NULL` and `ID` is used in update to allow the passed `id` to be edited.